# setAttribute does not change after setting it once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update the attribute of a button based on the selected value of a dropdown. However, the attribute doesn't change as expected.

Here's a summarized version of my code:

```
const planToSellixMap = {
    77: "123ABC",
    78: "321CBA",
    // ... other mappings
};

function generateProductList() {
    // ... rest of the function

    durationDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const selectedPlanId = parseInt(durationDropdown.value);
        updateButton(buyButton, selectedPlanId);
    });

    // ... rest of the function
}

function updateButton(buyButton, planId) {
    const sellixProduct = planToSellixMap[planId];
    if (sellixProduct) {
        buyButton.setAttribute("data-sellix-product", sellixProduct);
    } else {
        console.error(`Plan ID ${planId} does not have a corresponding sellix product.`);
    }
}

generateProductList();
```

The expected behavior is:
When the dropdown value is `77`, the button's data-sellix-product attribute should be set to `123ABC`.
When the dropdown value is `78`, the button's data-sellix-product attribute should be set to `321CBA`.
However, the button's attribute remains the same and doesn't update based on the dropdown's selection.

What I Already tried:

- Setting the attribute using an if statement, which didn't change the value after setting it once for some reason (with removeAttribute and without)
- Setting the attribute using `switch(planId){ case 77:...`etc. which was extremely confusing because console logging it showed that it was set correctly but after clicking the button it was `null`
- Various workarounds for `setAttribute` I found on the internet, but nothing worked as it should.

What might be causing this and how can I resolve it?

```js
const durationDropdown = document.getElementById("durationDropdown");
const buyButton = document.getElementById("buyButton");

const planToSellixMap = {
    77: "123ABC",
    78: "321CBA",
    // ... other mappings
};

function generateProductList() {
    // ... rest of the function

    durationDropdown.addEventListener("change", function () {
        const selectedPlanId = parseInt(durationDropdown.value);
        updateButton(buyButton, selectedPlanId);
    });

    // ... rest of the function
}

function updateButton(buyButton, planId) {
    const sellixProduct = planToSellixMap[planId];
    if (sellixProduct) {
        buyButton.setAttribute("data-sellix-product", sellixProduct);
    } else {
        console.error(
            `Plan ID ${planId} does not have a corresponding sellix product.`
        );
    }
}

generateProductList();
```

```html
<select id="durationDropdown">
    <option>76</option>
    <option>77</option>
    <option>78</option>
</select>
<input id="buyButton" type="button" value="Buy">
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: How do you know the attribute value does not change?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I did not get any further. As I already mentioned, the attribue for the first selected value gets set but after that it does not change anymore.

Comment: Have you logged the selected `planId` in the button update function?

Comment: Also what does this have to do with Node?

Comment: The original values are sellix product ID's, if I click on the button I see the product which corresponds with the product ID.

Comment: Right, but I'm asking about *debugging* work. Are you getting the expected values in the "change" handler? Is it being passed correctly to the `updateButton()` function? Have you added a `.getAttribute()` in that function to test the updated value of the attribute to verify it's correct?

Comment: added node.js by mistake, sorry for that i have edited the question

Comment: Yes, I added a console.log(getAttribute...), but after changing the dropdown value it does not gets triggered

Comment: So is the "change" event handler being triggered? Are you sure you are adding the event handler in the right place? You really haven't posted enough information and code for anybody to know what the problem is. Your browser is not broken; `.setAttribute()` will in fact set an attribute value on a DOM element.